# How to get the deleted temp file names list and read only file names list using windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tried to delete the temp files and display the deleted file and read only file names.

The below code i used for deleting the files and displaying the read only files.

```
@echo off
cd %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
del /f /q
```

but for me after deleting the files it should list and display the deleted file names.i guess we have to create some object/variable and store the file names.

is there any option to get it stored the file names and get it later?

Comment: A list of read-only files can be produced by `DIR /S /B /A:R`.

Answer (score 0):

This will list your readonly files.

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('robocopy /l /e /xa:R %temp% "nothing ..//" /njh /ndl /ns /nc /pf /njs')do @echo %i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving everything to a seperate folder first and then

```
dir /b /path/to/folder
```

to get the files you are able to delete and

```
dir /b %tmp%
```

to get the files you are unable to delete.

Comment: What if the `temp` folder contains files worth of GBs? Copying them to another folder would be such a wrong idea then.